# Adjuntar imagen que viene de la base de datos sql server y C#

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

Tengo este codigo con el cual cargo la imagen desde la base de datos usando sqldatareader, el campo es varbinary y lo muestro en un PictureBox.

```
imagebyte = (byte[])readerimage[14];
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagebyte, 0, imagebyte.Length);
                    ImgPic.Image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);//aqui muestro la imagen en el picturebox.
```

y en otro metodo quiero adjuntar esa imagen y aqui me surge la duda.
 Como puedo adjuntar esta imagen?
El correo no hay problema, solo no se como lo haria para obtener esa imagen y adjuntarla.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.Attachments.Add();//aqui quiero pasarle la imagen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias adjuntar el `byte[]` usando

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(imagebyte), "NombreImagen.jpg"));
```

debes definir un nombre para imagen, sera la que veas en el adjunto del mail.

Para obtener la imagen debes convertir el `image` del picturebox

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return  ms.ToArray();
}
```

Lo usarias

```
byte[] imagen = imageToByteArray(ImgPic.Image);
```